# How to get a list of all supported timezones?

Tags: node.js, timezone

How can we get a list of all supported timezones in NodeJs at runtime?

use-cases:

- we want to implement a check when the application starts to make sure that the main timezone (set via env-var) is correct).
- we want to show a list to the user so that they can select only valid time-zones

The [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/intl.html) mention that node can be used with different ICU settings, so a hardcoded list (like [timezones.json](https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json)) will not work.

I found some related questions, but none seems to answer this (simple?) question...
e.g. [Where does Node.js get the Timezone data from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477931/where-does-node-js-get-the-timezone-data-from)

Comment: Note that IANA names (e.g. `America/Los_Angeles`) and common time zone names (e.g. `PDT`) are different things.   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69961228 and https://medium.com/@EyeDin/time-and-time-zone-headaches-in-javascript-ae4d873a665d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

NodeJs >= 18 supports [Intl.supportedValuesOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/supportedValuesOf)

```js
Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')
```

## Original

I think that currently there is no easy way to get the list of supported timezones in node.js at runtime:

- JavaScript Internationalization Api:
  The [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma402) does not provide a way to get the list of supported timezones
- NodeJs:
  [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/intl.html) also does not provide a way go get the list of supported timezones

#### Workaround

A workaround is to somehow get a list of timezones and test each one separately.

There are many predefined timezone lists:

- [IANA Timezone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)
- [Wikipedia: List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
- [Json Timezone List](https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json)
- [Csv Timezone List](https://github.com/bproctor/timezones/blob/master/timezones.csv)

However, since we have a database application, we first get the list of all timezones supported by the database - see [PostgreSql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/view-pg-timezone-names.html):

```sql
SELECT name
FROM pg_timezone_names
ORDER BY name;
```

and then check for each one if it is supported by nodejs (here's some typescript pseudo code):

```typescript
  try {
    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
      timeZone
    })
    // timezone is valid - add to the valid list
  } catch (e) {
    // timezone is invalid - maybe write a log msg
  }
```

[Stackblitz Test](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tz?file=index.ts)

Now we have a list of all timezones that are valid in the database and in NodeJs.

There are currently (PostgreSql `12`, NodeJs `14`):

- `547` valid timezones
- `49` invalid timezones (i.e. known by PostgreSql, but not by NodeJs): e.g. `America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia`, `US/Alaska`, ..

Answer (score 3):

If you need a detailed JSON file, check out https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json.

However, if you just need the names (e.g. `America/Los_Angeles`) in a JSON array, the following 3-liner script in Node.js would work to get that from [timezones.json](https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json).

```js
const namesSet = new Set();
require("timezones.json").forEach((tzDefinition) => tzDefinition.utc.forEach((tzName) => namesSet.add(tzName)));
console.log(JSON.stringify([...namesSet].sort()));
```

Output on 2021/11/14 from `"timezones.json": "1.5.3"`:

```
["Africa/Abidjan","Africa/Accra","Africa/Addis_Ababa","Africa/Algiers","Africa/Asmera","Africa/Bamako","Africa/Bangui","Africa/Banjul","Africa/Bissau","Africa/Blantyre","Africa/Brazzaville","Africa/Bujumbura","Africa/Cairo","Africa/Casablanca","Africa/Ceuta","Africa/Conakry","Africa/Dakar","Africa/Dar_es_Salaam","Africa/Djibouti","Africa/Douala","Africa/El_Aaiun","Africa/Freetown","Africa/Gaborone","Africa/Harare","Africa/Johannesburg","Africa/Juba","Africa/Kampala","Africa/Khartoum","Africa/Kigali","Africa/Kinshasa","Africa/Lagos","Africa/Libreville","Africa/Lome","Africa/Luanda","Africa/Lubumbashi","Africa/Lusaka","Africa/Malabo","Africa/Maputo","Africa/Maseru","Africa/Mbabane","Africa/Mogadishu","Africa/Monrovia","Africa/Nairobi","Africa/Ndjamena","Africa/Niamey","Africa/Nouakchott","Africa/Ouagadougou","Africa/Porto-Novo","Africa/Sao_Tome","Africa/Tripoli","Africa/Tunis","Africa/Windhoek","America/Anchorage","America/Anguilla","America/Antigua","America/Araguaina","America/Argentina/La_Rioja","America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos","America/Argentina/Salta","America/Argentina/San_Juan","America/Argentina/San_Luis","America/Argentina/Tucuman","America/Argentina/Ushuaia","America/Aruba","America/Asuncion","America/Bahia","America/Bahia_Banderas","America/Barbados","America/Belem","America/Belize","America/Blanc-Sablon","America/Boa_Vista","America/Bogota","America/Boise","America/Buenos_Aires","America/Cambridge_Bay","America/Campo_Grande","America/Cancun","America/Caracas","America/Catamarca","America/Cayenne","America/Cayman","America/Chicago","America/Chihuahua","America/Coral_Harbour","America/Cordoba","America/Costa_Rica","America/Creston","America/Cuiaba","America/Curacao","America/Danmarkshavn","America/Dawson","America/Dawson_Creek","America/Denver","America/Detroit","America/Dominica","America/Edmonton","America/Eirunepe","America/El_Salvador","America/Fortaleza","America/Glace_Bay","America/Godthab","America/Goose_Bay","America/Grand_Turk","America/Grenada","America/Guadeloupe","America/Guatemala","America/Guayaquil","America/Guyana","America/Halifax","America/Havana","America/Hermosillo","America/Indiana/Knox","America/Indiana/Marengo","America/Indiana/Petersburg","America/Indiana/Tell_City","America/Indiana/Vevay","America/Indiana/Vincennes","America/Indiana/Winamac","America/Indianapolis","America/Inuvik","America/Iqaluit","America/Jamaica","America/Jujuy","America/Juneau","America/Kentucky/Monticello","America/Kralendijk","America/La_Paz","America/Lima","America/Los_Angeles","America/Louisville","America/Lower_Princes","America/Maceio","America/Managua","America/Manaus","America/Marigot","America/Martinique","America/Matamoros","America/Mazatlan","America/Mendoza","America/Menominee","America/Merida","America/Mexico_City","America/Moncton","America/Monterrey","America/Montevideo","America/Montreal","America/Montserrat","America/Nassau","America/New_York","America/Nipigon","America/Nome","America/Noronha","America/North_Dakota/Beulah","America/North_Dakota/Center","America/North_Dakota/New_Salem","America/Ojinaga","America/Panama","America/Pangnirtung","America/Paramaribo","America/Phoenix","America/Port-au-Prince","America/Port_of_Spain","America/Porto_Velho","America/Puerto_Rico","America/Rainy_River","America/Rankin_Inlet","America/Recife","America/Regina","America/Resolute","America/Rio_Branco","America/Santa_Isabel","America/Santarem","America/Santiago","America/Santo_Domingo","America/Sao_Paulo","America/Scoresbysund","America/Sitka","America/St_Barthelemy","America/St_Johns","America/St_Kitts","America/St_Lucia","America/St_Thomas","America/St_Vincent","America/Swift_Current","America/Tegucigalpa","America/Thule","America/Thunder_Bay","America/Tijuana","America/Toronto","America/Tortola","America/Vancouver","America/Whitehorse","America/Winnipeg","America/Yakutat","America/Yellowknife","Antarctica/Casey","Antarctica/Davis","Antarctica/DumontDUrville","Antarctica/Macquarie","Antarctica/Mawson","Antarctica/McMurdo","Antarctica/Palmer","Antarctica/Rothera","Antarctica/Syowa","Antarctica/Vostok","Arctic/Longyearbyen","Asia/Aden","Asia/Almaty","Asia/Amman","Asia/Anadyr","Asia/Aqtau","Asia/Aqtobe","Asia/Ashgabat","Asia/Baghdad","Asia/Bahrain","Asia/Baku","Asia/Bangkok","Asia/Beirut","Asia/Bishkek","Asia/Brunei","Asia/Calcutta","Asia/Chita","Asia/Choibalsan","Asia/Colombo","Asia/Damascus","Asia/Dhaka","Asia/Dili","Asia/Dubai","Asia/Dushanbe","Asia/Hong_Kong","Asia/Hovd","Asia/Irkutsk","Asia/Jakarta","Asia/Jayapura","Asia/Jerusalem","Asia/Kabul","Asia/Kamchatka","Asia/Karachi","Asia/Kathmandu","Asia/Khandyga","Asia/Kolkata","Asia/Krasnoyarsk","Asia/Kuala_Lumpur","Asia/Kuching","Asia/Kuwait","Asia/Macau","Asia/Magadan","Asia/Makassar","Asia/Manila","Asia/Muscat","Asia/Nicosia","Asia/Novokuznetsk","Asia/Novosibirsk","Asia/Omsk","Asia/Oral","Asia/Phnom_Penh","Asia/Pontianak","Asia/Pyongyang","Asia/Qatar","Asia/Qyzylorda","Asia/Rangoon","Asia/Riyadh","Asia/Saigon","Asia/Sakhalin","Asia/Samarkand","Asia/Seoul","Asia/Shanghai","Asia/Singapore","Asia/Srednekolymsk","Asia/Taipei","Asia/Tashkent","Asia/Tbilisi","Asia/Tehran","Asia/Thimphu","Asia/Tokyo","Asia/Ulaanbaatar","Asia/Urumqi","Asia/Ust-Nera","Asia/Vientiane","Asia/Vladivostok","Asia/Yakutsk","Asia/Yekaterinburg","Asia/Yerevan","Atlantic/Azores","Atlantic/Bermuda","Atlantic/Canary","Atlantic/Cape_Verde","Atlantic/Faeroe","Atlantic/Madeira","Atlantic/Reykjavik","Atlantic/South_Georgia","Atlantic/St_Helena","Atlantic/Stanley","Australia/Adelaide","Australia/Brisbane","Australia/Broken_Hill","Australia/Currie","Australia/Darwin","Australia/Hobart","Australia/Lindeman","Australia/Melbourne","Australia/Perth","Australia/Sydney","CST6CDT","EST5EDT","Etc/GMT","Etc/GMT+1","Etc/GMT+10","Etc/GMT+11","Etc/GMT+12","Etc/GMT+2","Etc/GMT+3","Etc/GMT+4","Etc/GMT+5","Etc/GMT+6","Etc/GMT+7","Etc/GMT-1","Etc/GMT-10","Etc/GMT-11","Etc/GMT-12","Etc/GMT-13","Etc/GMT-2","Etc/GMT-3","Etc/GMT-4","Etc/GMT-5","Etc/GMT-6","Etc/GMT-7","Etc/GMT-8","Etc/GMT-9","Europe/Amsterdam","Europe/Andorra","Europe/Astrakhan","Europe/Athens","Europe/Belgrade","Europe/Berlin","Europe/Bratislava","Europe/Brussels","Europe/Bucharest","Europe/Budapest","Europe/Busingen","Europe/Chisinau","Europe/Copenhagen","Europe/Dublin","Europe/Gibraltar","Europe/Guernsey","Europe/Helsinki","Europe/Isle_of_Man","Europe/Istanbul","Europe/Jersey","Europe/Kaliningrad","Europe/Kiev","Europe/Kirov","Europe/Lisbon","Europe/Ljubljana","Europe/London","Europe/Luxembourg","Europe/Madrid","Europe/Malta","Europe/Mariehamn","Europe/Minsk","Europe/Monaco","Europe/Moscow","Europe/Nicosia","Europe/Oslo","Europe/Paris","Europe/Podgorica","Europe/Prague","Europe/Riga","Europe/Rome","Europe/Samara","Europe/San_Marino","Europe/Sarajevo","Europe/Simferopol","Europe/Skopje","Europe/Sofia","Europe/Stockholm","Europe/Tallinn","Europe/Tirane","Europe/Ulyanovsk","Europe/Uzhgorod","Europe/Vaduz","Europe/Vatican","Europe/Vienna","Europe/Vilnius","Europe/Volgograd","Europe/Warsaw","Europe/Zagreb","Europe/Zaporozhye","Europe/Zurich","Indian/Antananarivo","Indian/Chagos","Indian/Christmas","Indian/Cocos","Indian/Comoro","Indian/Kerguelen","Indian/Mahe","Indian/Maldives","Indian/Mauritius","Indian/Mayotte","Indian/Reunion","MST7MDT","PST8PDT","Pacific/Apia","Pacific/Auckland","Pacific/Efate","Pacific/Enderbury","Pacific/Fakaofo","Pacific/Fiji","Pacific/Funafuti","Pacific/Galapagos","Pacific/Guadalcanal","Pacific/Guam","Pacific/Honolulu","Pacific/Johnston","Pacific/Kosrae","Pacific/Kwajalein","Pacific/Majuro","Pacific/Midway","Pacific/Nauru","Pacific/Niue","Pacific/Noumea","Pacific/Pago_Pago","Pacific/Palau","Pacific/Ponape","Pacific/Port_Moresby","Pacific/Rarotonga","Pacific/Saipan","Pacific/Tahiti","Pacific/Tarawa","Pacific/Tongatapu","Pacific/Truk","Pacific/Wake","Pacific/Wallis"]
```

Pretty-printed:

```
// 434 entries extracted from "timezones.json@1.5.3" package at 2021-11-14T20:03:29.078Z
[
    "Africa/Abidjan",
    "Africa/Accra",
    "Africa/Addis_Ababa",
    "Africa/Algiers",
    "Africa/Asmera",
    "Africa/Bamako",
    "Africa/Bangui",
    "Africa/Banjul",
    "Africa/Bissau",
    "Africa/Blantyre",
    "Africa/Brazzaville",
    "Africa/Bujumbura",
    "Africa/Cairo",
    "Africa/Casablanca",
    "Africa/Ceuta",
    "Africa/Conakry",
    "Africa/Dakar",
    "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam",
    "Africa/Djibouti",
    "Africa/Douala",
    "Africa/El_Aaiun",
    "Africa/Freetown",
    "Africa/Gaborone",
    "Africa/Harare",
    "Africa/Johannesburg",
    "Africa/Juba",
    "Africa/Kampala",
    "Africa/Khartoum",
    "Africa/Kigali",
    "Africa/Kinshasa",
    "Africa/Lagos",
    "Africa/Libreville",
    "Africa/Lome",
    "Africa/Luanda",
    "Africa/Lubumbashi",
    "Africa/Lusaka",
    "Africa/Malabo",
    "Africa/Maputo",
    "Africa/Maseru",
    "Africa/Mbabane",
    "Africa/Mogadishu",
    "Africa/Monrovia",
    "Africa/Nairobi",
    "Africa/Ndjamena",
    "Africa/Niamey",
    "Africa/Nouakchott",
    "Africa/Ouagadougou",
    "Africa/Porto-Novo",
    "Africa/Sao_Tome",
    "Africa/Tripoli",
    "Africa/Tunis",
    "Africa/Windhoek",
    "America/Anchorage",
    "America/Anguilla",
    "America/Antigua",
    "America/Araguaina",
    "America/Argentina/La_Rioja",
    "America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos",
    "America/Argentina/Salta",
    "America/Argentina/San_Juan",
    "America/Argentina/San_Luis",
    "America/Argentina/Tucuman",
    "America/Argentina/Ushuaia",
    "America/Aruba",
    "America/Asuncion",
    "America/Bahia",
    "America/Bahia_Banderas",
    "America/Barbados",
    "America/Belem",
    "America/Belize",
    "America/Blanc-Sablon",
    "America/Boa_Vista",
    "America/Bogota",
    "America/Boise",
    "America/Buenos_Aires",
    "America/Cambridge_Bay",
    "America/Campo_Grande",
    "America/Cancun",
    "America/Caracas",
    "America/Catamarca",
    "America/Cayenne",
    "America/Cayman",
    "America/Chicago",
    "America/Chihuahua",
    "America/Coral_Harbour",
    "America/Cordoba",
    "America/Costa_Rica",
    "America/Creston",
    "America/Cuiaba",
    "America/Curacao",
    "America/Danmarkshavn",
    "America/Dawson",
    "America/Dawson_Creek",
    "America/Denver",
    "America/Detroit",
    "America/Dominica",
    "America/Edmonton",
    "America/Eirunepe",
    "America/El_Salvador",
    "America/Fortaleza",
    "America/Glace_Bay",
    "America/Godthab",
    "America/Goose_Bay",
    "America/Grand_Turk",
    "America/Grenada",
    "America/Guadeloupe",
    "America/Guatemala",
    "America/Guayaquil",
    "America/Guyana",
    "America/Halifax",
    "America/Havana",
    "America/Hermosillo",
    "America/Indiana/Knox",
    "America/Indiana/Marengo",
    "America/Indiana/Petersburg",
    "America/Indiana/Tell_City",
    "America/Indiana/Vevay",
    "America/Indiana/Vincennes",
    "America/Indiana/Winamac",
    "America/Indianapolis",
    "America/Inuvik",
    "America/Iqaluit",
    "America/Jamaica",
    "America/Jujuy",
    "America/Juneau",
    "America/Kentucky/Monticello",
    "America/Kralendijk",
    "America/La_Paz",
    "America/Lima",
    "America/Los_Angeles",
    "America/Louisville",
    "America/Lower_Princes",
    "America/Maceio",
    "America/Managua",
    "America/Manaus",
    "America/Marigot",
    "America/Martinique",
    "America/Matamoros",
    "America/Mazatlan",
    "America/Mendoza",
    "America/Menominee",
    "America/Merida",
    "America/Mexico_City",
    "America/Moncton",
    "America/Monterrey",
    "America/Montevideo",
    "America/Montreal",
    "America/Montserrat",
    "America/Nassau",
    "America/New_York",
    "America/Nipigon",
    "America/Nome",
    "America/Noronha",
    "America/North_Dakota/Beulah",
    "America/North_Dakota/Center",
    "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem",
    "America/Ojinaga",
    "America/Panama",
    "America/Pangnirtung",
    "America/Paramaribo",
    "America/Phoenix",
    "America/Port-au-Prince",
    "America/Port_of_Spain",
    "America/Porto_Velho",
    "America/Puerto_Rico",
    "America/Rainy_River",
    "America/Rankin_Inlet",
    "America/Recife",
    "America/Regina",
    "America/Resolute",
    "America/Rio_Branco",
    "America/Santa_Isabel",
    "America/Santarem",
    "America/Santiago",
    "America/Santo_Domingo",
    "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "America/Scoresbysund",
    "America/Sitka",
    "America/St_Barthelemy",
    "America/St_Johns",
    "America/St_Kitts",
    "America/St_Lucia",
    "America/St_Thomas",
    "America/St_Vincent",
    "America/Swift_Current",
    "America/Tegucigalpa",
    "America/Thule",
    "America/Thunder_Bay",
    "America/Tijuana",
    "America/Toronto",
    "America/Tortola",
    "America/Vancouver",
    "America/Whitehorse",
    "America/Winnipeg",
    "America/Yakutat",
    "America/Yellowknife",
    "Antarctica/Casey",
    "Antarctica/Davis",
    "Antarctica/DumontDUrville",
    "Antarctica/Macquarie",
    "Antarctica/Mawson",
    "Antarctica/McMurdo",
    "Antarctica/Palmer",
    "Antarctica/Rothera",
    "Antarctica/Syowa",
    "Antarctica/Vostok",
    "Arctic/Longyearbyen",
    "Asia/Aden",
    "Asia/Almaty",
    "Asia/Amman",
    "Asia/Anadyr",
    "Asia/Aqtau",
    "Asia/Aqtobe",
    "Asia/Ashgabat",
    "Asia/Baghdad",
    "Asia/Bahrain",
    "Asia/Baku",
    "Asia/Bangkok",
    "Asia/Beirut",
    "Asia/Bishkek",
    "Asia/Brunei",
    "Asia/Calcutta",
    "Asia/Chita",
    "Asia/Choibalsan",
    "Asia/Colombo",
    "Asia/Damascus",
    "Asia/Dhaka",
    "Asia/Dili",
    "Asia/Dubai",
    "Asia/Dushanbe",
    "Asia/Hong_Kong",
    "Asia/Hovd",
    "Asia/Irkutsk",
    "Asia/Jakarta",
    "Asia/Jayapura",
    "Asia/Jerusalem",
    "Asia/Kabul",
    "Asia/Kamchatka",
    "Asia/Karachi",
    "Asia/Kathmandu",
    "Asia/Khandyga",
    "Asia/Kolkata",
    "Asia/Krasnoyarsk",
    "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur",
    "Asia/Kuching",
    "Asia/Kuwait",
    "Asia/Macau",
    "Asia/Magadan",
    "Asia/Makassar",
    "Asia/Manila",
    "Asia/Muscat",
    "Asia/Nicosia",
    "Asia/Novokuznetsk",
    "Asia/Novosibirsk",
    "Asia/Omsk",
    "Asia/Oral",
    "Asia/Phnom_Penh",
    "Asia/Pontianak",
    "Asia/Pyongyang",
    "Asia/Qatar",
    "Asia/Qyzylorda",
    "Asia/Rangoon",
    "Asia/Riyadh",
    "Asia/Saigon",
    "Asia/Sakhalin",
    "Asia/Samarkand",
    "Asia/Seoul",
    "Asia/Shanghai",
    "Asia/Singapore",
    "Asia/Srednekolymsk",
    "Asia/Taipei",
    "Asia/Tashkent",
    "Asia/Tbilisi",
    "Asia/Tehran",
    "Asia/Thimphu",
    "Asia/Tokyo",
    "Asia/Ulaanbaatar",
    "Asia/Urumqi",
    "Asia/Ust-Nera",
    "Asia/Vientiane",
    "Asia/Vladivostok",
    "Asia/Yakutsk",
    "Asia/Yekaterinburg",
    "Asia/Yerevan",
    "Atlantic/Azores",
    "Atlantic/Bermuda",
    "Atlantic/Canary",
    "Atlantic/Cape_Verde",
    "Atlantic/Faeroe",
    "Atlantic/Madeira",
    "Atlantic/Reykjavik",
    "Atlantic/South_Georgia",
    "Atlantic/St_Helena",
    "Atlantic/Stanley",
    "Australia/Adelaide",
    "Australia/Brisbane",
    "Australia/Broken_Hill",
    "Australia/Currie",
    "Australia/Darwin",
    "Australia/Hobart",
    "Australia/Lindeman",
    "Australia/Melbourne",
    "Australia/Perth",
    "Australia/Sydney",
    "CST6CDT",
    "EST5EDT",
    "Etc/GMT",
    "Etc/GMT+1",
    "Etc/GMT+10",
    "Etc/GMT+11",
    "Etc/GMT+12",
    "Etc/GMT+2",
    "Etc/GMT+3",
    "Etc/GMT+4",
    "Etc/GMT+5",
    "Etc/GMT+6",
    "Etc/GMT+7",
    "Etc/GMT-1",
    "Etc/GMT-10",
    "Etc/GMT-11",
    "Etc/GMT-12",
    "Etc/GMT-13",
    "Etc/GMT-2",
    "Etc/GMT-3",
    "Etc/GMT-4",
    "Etc/GMT-5",
    "Etc/GMT-6",
    "Etc/GMT-7",
    "Etc/GMT-8",
    "Etc/GMT-9",
    "Europe/Amsterdam",
    "Europe/Andorra",
    "Europe/Astrakhan",
    "Europe/Athens",
    "Europe/Belgrade",
    "Europe/Berlin",
    "Europe/Bratislava",
    "Europe/Brussels",
    "Europe/Bucharest",
    "Europe/Budapest",
    "Europe/Busingen",
    "Europe/Chisinau",
    "Europe/Copenhagen",
    "Europe/Dublin",
    "Europe/Gibraltar",
    "Europe/Guernsey",
    "Europe/Helsinki",
    "Europe/Isle_of_Man",
    "Europe/Istanbul",
    "Europe/Jersey",
    "Europe/Kaliningrad",
    "Europe/Kiev",
    "Europe/Kirov",
    "Europe/Lisbon",
    "Europe/Ljubljana",
    "Europe/London",
    "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "Europe/Madrid",
    "Europe/Malta",
    "Europe/Mariehamn",
    "Europe/Minsk",
    "Europe/Monaco",
    "Europe/Moscow",
    "Europe/Nicosia",
    "Europe/Oslo",
    "Europe/Paris",
    "Europe/Podgorica",
    "Europe/Prague",
    "Europe/Riga",
    "Europe/Rome",
    "Europe/Samara",
    "Europe/San_Marino",
    "Europe/Sarajevo",
    "Europe/Simferopol",
    "Europe/Skopje",
    "Europe/Sofia",
    "Europe/Stockholm",
    "Europe/Tallinn",
    "Europe/Tirane",
    "Europe/Ulyanovsk",
    "Europe/Uzhgorod",
    "Europe/Vaduz",
    "Europe/Vatican",
    "Europe/Vienna",
    "Europe/Vilnius",
    "Europe/Volgograd",
    "Europe/Warsaw",
    "Europe/Zagreb",
    "Europe/Zaporozhye",
    "Europe/Zurich",
    "Indian/Antananarivo",
    "Indian/Chagos",
    "Indian/Christmas",
    "Indian/Cocos",
    "Indian/Comoro",
    "Indian/Kerguelen",
    "Indian/Mahe",
    "Indian/Maldives",
    "Indian/Mauritius",
    "Indian/Mayotte",
    "Indian/Reunion",
    "MST7MDT",
    "PST8PDT",
    "Pacific/Apia",
    "Pacific/Auckland",
    "Pacific/Efate",
    "Pacific/Enderbury",
    "Pacific/Fakaofo",
    "Pacific/Fiji",
    "Pacific/Funafuti",
    "Pacific/Galapagos",
    "Pacific/Guadalcanal",
    "Pacific/Guam",
    "Pacific/Honolulu",
    "Pacific/Johnston",
    "Pacific/Kosrae",
    "Pacific/Kwajalein",
    "Pacific/Majuro",
    "Pacific/Midway",
    "Pacific/Nauru",
    "Pacific/Niue",
    "Pacific/Noumea",
    "Pacific/Pago_Pago",
    "Pacific/Palau",
    "Pacific/Ponape",
    "Pacific/Port_Moresby",
    "Pacific/Rarotonga",
    "Pacific/Saipan",
    "Pacific/Tahiti",
    "Pacific/Tarawa",
    "Pacific/Tongatapu",
    "Pacific/Truk",
    "Pacific/Wake",
    "Pacific/Wallis",
]
```

Note that any mapping from "Name" to anything (even text) wouldn't be unique -- e.g. `America/Los_Angeles` appears in two entries for with and without DST [here](https://github.com/dmfilipenko/timezones.json/blob/master/timezones.json#L64-L87).

The output of this can be dumped into a JSON5 file (last line has comment) and stored in your repo.  You can run this script every now and then to get updated list.

---

A more detailed script that I wrote and I am actually going to store for generating this code is avaiable at: https://gist.github.com/eyedean/18f2611624c8f9624f8bc6a3b74e9dba