# Update node's timezone data without upgrading node

Tags: node.js, docker, timezone

Inside a docker image created from `node:16.20-alpine`, if I run `node` and then `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Africa/Cairo"})` I see a time that is 2 hours ahead of UTC, when at the time of writing they are 3. This is because Cairo this year introduced DST, which this version of node does not know about. Is it possible to fix this without upgrading the version of node (like https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/47818 suggests)? Just by patching the timezone data itself somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does Node.js get the Timezone data from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477931/where-does-node-js-get-the-timezone-data-from)

Answer (score -1):

This is how we had done it in `gradle` based docker image. Try following content in your Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.20-alpine

ENV TZ=Africa/Cairo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: Thank you, however I do not want to set the local timezone to Cairo which I believe this does? Simply to make it such that formatting a time in a specific timezone returns correctly

Comment: The question sounds like the data in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` (or somewhere more Node-specific) is out of date, so just setting a system time zone won't help.